# JavaScript Application и авторизация через OAuth 2

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, oauth2

**Дано:**

- Основной сайт (PHP+HTML) с поднятым [OAuth 2 сервером](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/)
- Доверенное приложение на этом же домене на [Angular-е](https://angularjs.org) (100% javascript)

**Задача:**

1. Авторизация пользователей в приложении через собственный OAuth сервер (точнее нужен токен для доступа к апи)
2. "Запомнить меня" (каждый раз тыкать кнопку и делать кучку редиректов не вариант)

**Размышления:**

Сама спецификация предусматривает для таких случаев Implicit Grant, но как реализовать "запомнить" я так и не придумал ибо срок жизни токена ограничен, а получить новый можно только через редиректы => оно неюзабельно.

Кроме того, например, [вон там рассказывается](http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/) что оно не безопасно и дана гениальная идея использовать proxy и шифрованные кукисы для скрытия токенов (`refresh_token` получается недоступен в js, но сохраняется в кукисах и может потом использоваться повторно) - однако, я так и не понял что помешает использовать этот proxy напрямую? (имхо, бессмысленное усложнение, возможно, ошибаюсь?)

Следующей после после proxy была идея забить на спецификацию и использовать Authorisation Code Grant с открытым `client_secret` - благодаря наличию `refresh_token`-а можно будет получать новые токены и оставаться авторизованным. НО этот вариант по сути мало чем отличается от Implicit Grant с "вечным" токеном + из-за большего количества действий реализация получается немного сложнее.

**Решение?**

В итоге после прочтения тонны всяких статей на тему js + oauth и размышлений <s>о том как же оно всё криво</s> изложенных выше остановился на следующем варианте: используя Client Credentials Grant выполняем ajax `POST` на основной сайт и если пользователь там авторизован ("там" оно определяется по cookies) и ранее уже авторизовал приложение, то сразу возвращаем токен (это и будет "запомнить меня"), если нет, то получаем первый токен через Implicit Grant. Естественно это всё только при `https`, `POST`, `X-Frame-Options: DENY` и всё на одном домене. Вроде бы оно не сильно дыряво получается?

---

В общем то, **хотелось бы услышать критику** или предложите **какой-нибудь другой вариант**, себе уже всю голову сломал :(

Answer (score 6):

Вы, ровно как и Алекс Билби сильно преувеличиваете опасность авторизации клиентских приложений в OAuth2.

Естественно, в фронтенде публичного веб-приложения не стоит организовывать получение прав через `Resource Owner Password Credentials`(когда OAuth-серверу для получения токена передаётся id приложения + логин/пароль пользователя). Не стоит использовать и `Client Credentials`(OAuth-серверу передаётся только id приложения, а авторизация происходит с использованием внешних систем - например через NTLM-хеш, либо через HTTP-basic-авторизацию). Впрочем, оба этих способа очень специфичны, и абсолютное большинство OAuth-серверов их просто-напросто не поддерживают...

Для авторизации остаются только Explicit(Authorization Code) и Implicit.

`Explicit` требует наличия веб-сервера. При этом `access token` клиенту не передаётся - клиентской стороне возвращается "статус" и "код авторизации", тот передаёт серверу приложения, а он используя код авторизации получает от OAuth-сервера токен доступа. Дополнительно(но не всегда обязательно) при получении токена доступа серверу приложения требуется отправить "client secret" - специальный код/пароль, по которому определяется подлинность вашего приложения, и без указания которого нельзя получить токен доступа.

`Implict` не требует наличия веб-сервера, при этом токен доступа возвращается в url. И естественно "client secret" в этом случае не используется - OAuth-серверу отправляется только id приложение, которое собственно по определению не является секретной информацией(любой может просто скопировать его из url авторизации, даже при explicit-авторизации).

Злоумышленник потенциально может украсть как токен доступа при Implicit авторизации, так и авторизационные cookies вашего сайта. Основным каналом утечки при этом являются XSS-уязвимости на вашем сайте, либо вредоносное ПО на компьютере пользователя.

Что злоумышленник получит в случае кражи токена доступа/cookies? Для практически всё! И не важно, что применялась Explicit-авторизация и вы проксировали запросы - всю необходимую информацию он получит через ваш сайт.

Основное преимущество "проксирования" состоит в том, что иногда поставщики OAuth-ресурсов создают чересчур широкие `scope`, включающие заведомо больший функционал, нежели необходимо вашему приложению(несмотря на спецификацию, требующую минимальность) - в этом случае вы можете отрезать доступ к нежелательным ресурсам на уровне вашего бекенда.

Но и минус тоже есть - при Explicit-авторизации, в случае взлома вашего сервера, злоумышленник получит из хранилища токены доступа сразу всех пользователей приложения. В случае же Implict-авторизации, взломав ваш сервер, злоумышленник токены доступа пользователей сразу не получит(ему придется предваритально модифицировать код фронтенда, да выдирать сохраненные на клиентской стороне токены).

Comment: Не думаю что преувеличиваю: при использовании Implict на клиенте весьма проблематично реализовать "запомнить меня" (разве что создав токен с большим временем жизни, но это не избавит от необходимости периодически тыкать на кнопку) из-за того что разрешать авторизацию в iframe, имхо, не безопасно, особенно если в дальнейшем клиент переедет на отдельный домен (а это по сути единственный вариант получить хеш из урла после всех перенаправлений) + сейчас для подтверждения пользователь всегда должен ответить "согласен" (т.е. автоматического редиректа обратно в данный момент нет).

Comment: Т.е. тут проблема больше в том как сделать "запомнить меня" чтобы это всё было прозрачно для пользователя. Explicit с `refresh_token` можно использовать, но и получение и отслеживание актуальности токенов получается сложнее чем в варианте с Client Credentials (где по сути нужен только ajax запрос, что выглядит довольно удобно).

Comment: @LastDragon, что мешает сохранять токен в Cookies(сессионном или постоянном - без разницы), да получать его заново при истечении его срока действия? "Тыканья на кнопки" здесь нет. Диалог подтверждения прав пользователю показывается OAuth-сервером обычно только в первый раз - в последующие разы происходит просто выдача нового токена. Переадресацию хоть в раз в год, хоть при каждом начале работы с приложением пользователь вполне себе переживёт - оно занимает секунду или даже меньше. Для пользователя внешнее это выглядит именно как функция "запомнить меня".

Comment: Ничего не мешает кроме ограниченного срока жизни токена (вечный токен не есть хорошо), диалога (который отключать не хочется, ибо пользователи сами все равно никогда не найдут как удалить приложение). Выглядит оно не как "запомнить", а как два редиректа после открытия приложения - не юзабельно и раздражает (особенно печально будет на медленных каналах). А еще при Client Credentials получаем по сути single sign on что в общем то хорошо (если пользователь вышел с сайта то и из приложения, с `refresh_token` так не получится).